# How to simplify a proposed dictionary of different keys

Tags: python

I built a graph using `NetworkX` library. I used `all_shortest_paths(graph, src, dest)` that returns **a list** of a all possible shortest paths from a given source and a given destination (For example, between node 3 and 4 it may return [[3,5,4],[3,5,7,6,4]]). For the sake of my experiment, I want to store every returned list in a dictionary. My problem is how to utilize Python dictionary to do so. If I use the following scenario, it will be complicated:

```
dict = {'n1':['n2':[n1,n3,n4,n2], 'n3':[n1,n7,n3]], 'n2':['n6':[n2,n6,n8,n10,n2]], ...}
```

Is it possible in Python to have dictionary inside a dictionary where the the key will be src node and the value is another dictionary of a key dest and value all possible paths to the destination.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: "path from any src node to all its neighbors" - but you can get from a node to any of its neighbors in one step. Otherwise they wouldn't be neighbors.

Comment: I apologize .. I mean the destination not the neighbor . It is fixed ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could represent your graph as an adjacency matrix. This is just a 2-dimensional array of 1's and 0's, of size (number of nodes x number of nodes) with the rows and columns representing the nodes, and an entry of 1 at a row and column where the nodes represented are neighbors, and a 0 where the nodes represented by that row and column are not neighbors.

If you plan to do any extensive work with graphs in Python, I strongly recommend looking into the NetworkX Python package. It is documented at http://networkx.github.io/ . If you use the Anaconda scientific Python distribution, NetworkX comes with it.

There are other methods in NetworkX, like **all_pairs_shortest_path()**, and **floyd_warshall()**, that return their results as a dictionary of shortest paths by node, keyed by source and destination node.

And **all_pairs_shortest_path_length()**, which returns its results as a dictionary of shortest path lengths, keyed by source and destination node.

Possibly one of these might work for you?

Comment: The reason is that I am using NetworkX's method `all_shortest_paths(graph, src, dest)` that returns a list of all shortest path from a src to dest. I want to store this in a dict which why I don't know how

Comment: That's a little bit different than the original question, can you edit it to clarify? Do you want to represent the graph, or the shortest paths through it?

Comment: Thank you. You are right. I just updated the question.

Comment: is all_pairs_shortest_path() maybe what you want? It returns a dictionary of all shortest paths keyed by source and target nodes.

Comment: Actually it return only a list of all possible paths from source to destination. For example, when I tested between 4 and 5 (based on my graph), it printed the path from node 4 to node 5 as: `[[4, 2, 5], [4, 3, 5]]`. 
I just changed the question again for clarity. THANK YOU.

Comment: http://networkx.readthedocs.org/en/networkx-1.11/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.all_shortest_paths.html?highlight=all_shortest_paths#networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.all_shortest_paths